# javascript error with iframe in FF

Tags: javascript

I have the code like below,

```
var contentFrame = window.document.getElementById("globalSearch");
var content = contentFrame.document.getElementById("globalSearch");
```

Can some one please expalin me what is the difference between above two lines. in FF I'm getting error 'contentFrame.document is undefined'

and my form is something like below,

```
<form id="Search" action="<c:url value="/search" />" method="get">
<input .... />           
<iframe style="visibility : hidden;position : absolute;top : 0; border : 1px solid WindowFrame;"frameborder="0"            src="<c:url value="/search" />"
id="globalSearch" name="globalSearch"></iframe></form>
```

Is there anyway I can get rid of the above error? I would be gald if some one give me the equivalent code in jquery which works in all browsers.

Thank you again!

---

Actually, im my application, for every page a template being used. A template has header, footer menu html. the form shown below is defined in header.html

```
<form id="Search" action="<c:url value="/search" />" method="get"> 
  <input .... />            
  <iframe style="visibility : hidden;position : absolute;top : 0; border : 1px solid WindowFrame;" frameborder="0" src="<c:url value="/search" />" id="globalSearch" name="globalSearch"></iframe>
</form>
```

That is the reason the code is reffering the globalSearch iframe id(considering as child element of parent page) as below,

```
var contentFrame = window.document.getElementById("globalSearch"); 
var content = contentFrame.document.getElementById("globalSearch");
```

will `this->content=$(#globalSearch").contents();` works in this scenario? please clarify. Thanks in advance. this is very urgent. please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var contentFrame = window.document.getElementById("globalSearch");
var content = contentFrame.document.getElementById("globalSearch");
```

Only the first statement makes sense; the second one relies on the first and would search for `globalSearch` inside the iframe with id `globalSearch`.

Btw, you can shorten the first statement a bit:

```
var contentFrame = document.getElementById('globalSearch')
```

You don't need to specify `window`.

Comment: This is again a question..Actually, im my application, for every page a template being used. A template has header, footer menu html. the form shown below is defined in header.html " method="get">
 " id="globalSearch" name="globalSearch"> That is the reason the code is reffering the globalSearch iframe id(considering as child element of parent page) as below, var contentFrame = window.document.getElementById("globalSearch"); var content = contentFrame.document.getElementById("globalSearch"); will this->content=$(#globalSearch").contents(); works in this scenario? please clarify.